# How to make biblatex-chicago put a footnote before punctuation?

Tags: biblatex, punctuation, biblatex-chicago

I use the `\autocite` command from the package `biblatex-chicago` for referencing, and I use the `\footnote` command for other footnotes.

Usually, I want footnotes to appear after punctuation, but in rare cases, the footnote really only refers to a single word.
If a comma happens to follow that word, I want the footnote marker to appear before the comma.

While that works with `\footnote`, the `\autocite` command always places the footnote marker *after* the comma, even if the instruction stands before it.
Here’s an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}
\begin{document}
This is an example sentence%
\footnote{In linguistics, a sentence is a grammatical unit of language.},
and the footnote marker appears before the comma.

Here is another sentence%
\autocite[In law, a sentence is something different.][]{doesntexist},
and the footnote marker appears after the comma.
\end{document}
```

While in both cases the comma should come after the footnote marker, `biblatex-chicago` automatically switches their position.
Why does it happen and how can I change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a feature of `biblatex`'s `\autocite` command (and only the `\autocite` command, see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/733). If the `autopunct` option is activated, `\autocite` does not only scan ahead to suppress unwanted double punctuation, it can also move around the following punctuation mark if desired. All other cite commands only avoid double punctuation and do not move the punctuation mark.

With `autocite=footnote` `biblatex` moves the punctuation following a footnote marker issued by `\autocite` before the footnote marker - supposedly this gives a slightly nicer output.

If you don't want that you can disable that behaviour by redefining the `footnote` `autocite` setting

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}

\DeclareAutoCiteCommand{footnote}[r]{\smartcite}{\smartcites}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{autocite=footnote}

\begin{document}
This is an example sentence%
\footnote{In linguistics, a sentence is a grammatical unit of language.},
and the footnote marker appears before the comma.

Here is another sentence%
\autocite[In law, a sentence is something different.][]{doesntexist},
and the footnote marker appears after the comma.
\end{document}
```

[image]

The letter `r` in the optional argument tells `biblatex` not to move punctuation (i.e., to leave it to the right of the citation command), the value `l` would tell `biblatex` to move the following punctuation to the left of a citation. The default value for `footnote` was `f`, which behaves like `l` in normal text and like `r` in footnotes.

The additional `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{autocite=footnote}` is necessary because of https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/758.

Theoretically you could obtain the same output with `autopunct=false`, but that would also disable the detection of unwanted double punctuation.